# Naming the input when uploading with multiple Form::file - Laravel-5

Tags: php, forms, laravel, laravel-5

I have a form that has multiple form file uploads - 6. 
So it looks like this :

```
<div class='form-group'>
  <div class='row'>
    <div class='col-md-12'>
      <div class='btn btn-info btn-md'>
        {!!Form::file('image-1')!!}

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class='form-group'>
  <div class='row'>
    <div class='col-md-12'>
      <div class='btn btn-info btn-md'>
        {!!Form::file('image-2')!!}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In my controller, I don't want to have to do

```
if(Input::hasFile('image-1')||Input::hasFile('image-2')|| etc) {
  //code
}
```

plus each new image is a new row in my DB.  I REALLY don't want to do

$image-1 = Image::create();
$image-2 = Image::create();

I guess for this I could throw everything into a array and loop through it, creating a object through each iteration...But I would still need to create an array with all the input objects which is annoying.  Please show the way O_O

Answer (score 1, accepted):

name all the file inputs like,

```
{!!Form::file('images[]')!!}
```

then `images` is an `array`

you can get the input in laravel as,

```
$images = Request::input('images');
```

then you can use `foreach` on `$images` array and do what you want.